# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm trying to echo out the name of the user in my school.

For school table

```
Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->string('school_name');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('gender');
    $table->string('notes');
    $table->string('member_name');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->string('file_number');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('address');
});
```

For SchoolController

```
public function show(School $school)
{
    $province_names = Province::all();
    $city_names = City::all();
    $center_names = City::all();
    return view('school.all', compact('school','city_names', 'province_names', 'center_names'));
}
```

For model School

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

all.blade.php

```
{{ $school->user->firstـname }}
```

I get this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

But I writted `{{ dd($school->user) }}` display `null`.

Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
public function show($id) {
    $school = School::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first();

    // ...
}
```

Or auto-load relation on your model:

```php
class School extends Model {
    protected $with = ['user'];
}
```

Comment: Oh I got involved in three weeks. Thanks